# PhpStorm not recognize xdebug.remote_enable

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying PhpStorm with xdebug, but when I try to validate the configuration, shows me a warning: remote debug is not enabled, as shown the image bellow. In the same way phpinfo() shows xdebug.remote_enable as Off, and of course, debug doesn't work.

php.ini xdebug configuation:

```
[xdebug]

zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so

xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is an issue in remote port, you mentioned 9001 and php storm is looking for 9000, can you update and check it again?

Comment: You must be editing the wrogn php.ini file.. or have xdebug settings defined in a separate .ini file (that is parsed in addition to master file). Check `phpinfo()` output, first table: it has the config files used by that PHP installation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was editting wrong php.ini. The correct one is shown in Loaded Configuration File from phpinfo(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be editing wrong php.ini file.. or have Xdebug settings defined in a separate .ini file (that is parsed in addition to the master file).

On Linux & Mac it's quite common to have different php.ini for CLI and web server.

Check `phpinfo()` output, top table: it will show all config files used by that PHP installation.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue and I can see the remote_host value change so I'm definitely not editing the incorrect php.ini file (technically, I'm editing the 20-xdebug.ini in /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/ )

Comment: @Scott 1) What are you trying to debug: CLI script or a web page. 2) Please share whole `phpinfo()` output captured using the same environment where you are trying to debug. 3) Is this some "static"/traditional setup .. or a Docker container?. You better post it all as a new question here on SO.

Comment: I have a feeling that either phpstorm is doing something wrong or it's not parsing the value properly. but in my case, the problem turned out to be a misunderstanding of which way the actual xdebug traffic was going. I was aware the local machine makes a request but eventually figured out the side running the code then tries to talk 'back' to the address it received the request from. Once I realized this, I had to work out a janky work-around due to a firewall on this end in front of a NAT. (cont)

Comment: What I ended up doing was using the ssh connection I set up to forward local port 9000 (xdebug) to the remote computer to also forward the remote ssh port (22) back down to the local machine on port 10022. I start that and keep it open, then I set up PhpStorm to use the local port 10022 to do all of it's interaction with the remote. The remote then sees 'localhost' as the requesting machine and talks back to 127.0.0.1 instead of my NAT's public IP. That way the response comes back through port 9000 via the tunnel.

Comment: @Scott To me it sounds like some misunderstanding and therefore user misconfiguration of Xdebug. For CLI mode, IDE passes some of the Xdebug settings via command line when executing PHP script (values will differ for local/remote). It then starts to listen on Xdebug port (locally of course). Xdebug gets in when PHP executes the code. The "debug me" flag is passed by IDE for CLI. It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around (the most common mistake/assumption made).

Comment: @Scott Xdebug tries to connect to the IP/host specified in `xdebug.remote_host`. If your PHP is run on remote server, then using reverse SSH tunnel is the best way as it will pass you through the NAT/your router, otherwise you need to open and forward Xdebug port there to your local PC. Yes, if you are using reverse SSH then for Xdebug the `remote_host` param should be `127.0.0.1` -- SSH will accept the connection there and will forward it back to your local PC (check debugging docs in official PhpStorm help -- they have a section just for that).

Comment: @Scott Seems like you have done just that. If you have sorted it out and it works great -- then it's all sorted. But in any case: please check how Xdebug works and what PhpStorm help has about that: 1) https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: links like those is part of the problem I was having troubles. All of the examples relate to debugging web content in conjunction with an http request. What I was trying to do was just make sure a script would run in the remote environment. (specifically I need to verify connections/data in the remote end's mysql which isn't publicly exposed on a port, but instead uses a local socket). But I was able to get it working by tunnelling both the 9000 port and the ssh, then having phpstorm use the tunnel ports to connect so the remote php/xdebug thinks it's just talking to localhost.

Comment: (in other words, I couldn't simply tunnel the mysql connection to run code locally)

Answer (score 0):

Was also stuck 1+ hours on this problem, because the error message is not very helpful and sometimes misleading.

Maybe it's obvious, but try the following if everything else fails:

- place a phpinfo() somewhere in your project to read out your currently applied php.ini configuration
- open the php.ini you see under "Loaded Configuration File" in your phpinfo
- edit your debug config
- restart your webserver (This seems to be required when you start Laravel via "php artisan serve", at least in my case)
- load your phpinfo again to confirm that your settings have been applied
- run your PhpStorm debug config validator again

Your webserver and PhpStorm should now pick up your new debug configuration.